# Javascript event loop vs Node event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, event-loop, libuv

I am learning the basics of Node.js. One thing that constantly confuses me is the event loop. From what I have learned, Node.js handles asynchronous functions using threads in libuv. How does chrome V8 engine handles this?

Comment: JavaScript does not have an event loop. The event loop is only part of the engine. You could write an engine that only executes JS synchronously and has no event loop at all.

Comment: "*Libuv is not part of normal JavaScript engine.*" - what is "normal" to you?

Comment: Thanks for replying. So node developers took V8 engine and left out the event loop part and wrote something of their own?